# ¿Como enviar un String de un activity a un fragment antes que el activity finalice?

Tags: android, android-studio, activity, fragment

El caso es que, hago un formulario, y almaceno y obtengo los datos sin problema alguno, el problema esta en que, cuando la actividad hace lo que debe hacer, la misma debe finalizar, y por ende necesito recuperar esos datos antes que la misma termine y mostrarlos en el `fragment` donde se llama dicha actividad. He intentado de esta forma:

```
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("ITEM", item);
    Fragment info = new Fragment();
    info.setArguments(data);
    finish();
```

Pero para que esta información llegue al `fragment` tendría que hacer el `commit`, pero no puedo por que ya el `fragment` esta cargado, solo esperando la información para ser mostrada, y no quiero recargar el mismo.

Otra cosa que intente y logré fue con un `SharedPreferences`, y obtengo el valor tranquilamente, pero quisiera saber si existe un método para obtener estos datos sin la necesidad de emplear un `SharedPreferences` en cada caso que necesite salvar una data con ese problema, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

para devolver los datos al fragment podes utilizar lo siguiente:

Abris la actividad de esta forma:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, TU_ACTIVITY.class), NUMERO_IDENTIFICADOR);
```

En tu fragment sobreescribis el metodo onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == NUMERO_IDENTIFICADOR && data != null){
        //REALIZAS LO QUE TENGAS QUE HACER, LOS DATOS ESTAN EN DATA
  }
}
```

En tu actividad para finalizarla agregas lo siguiente

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
returnIntent.putExtra("datos",LOS_DATOS_QUE_NECESITAS_ENVIAR);
//PODES PONER VARIOS putExtra SI ES NECESARIO
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Para recolectar los datos desde el metodo onActivityResult es asi

```
String datos = data.getStringExtra("datos");
```

Comment: Perfecto, sirve para lo que necesitaba, gracias.

Comment: Me alegro!, saludos :D